# Infinitely nested radical question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, radicals, nested-radicals

Here is the problem: $\sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{3+4\sqrt{5+\cdots}}}$  I have been working on this problem for almost a week but I don't seem to find anything valuable to solve this. I found a pattern that goes like this : $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+2(1+2\sqrt{2+3(1+2\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}}$ But it seems like it is useless. And evaluated this equation too: $F(x)^2 = x+(x+1)F(x+2)$ But again this seems useless too. I am well too confused.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem. Tell us some of what you tried during the last "almost a week."

Comment: Why don't you paste the question in the question body? $\sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{3+4\sqrt{5+\cdots}}}$

Comment: Numerically, It seems to converge around 13...

Comment: @DhruvSomani Yes, I did take that into consideration... But, ya, the terms are almost $(2n-1)^{1/n}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical

Comment: @WinVineeth Hm, I get $\approx 3.59854454$ only!?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: He probably forgot the first radical: $3.6^2=12.96.$

Answer (score 3):

This nested radical should be interpreted as limit of $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{3+4\sqrt{5+\ldots+2n\sqrt{2n+1}}}}$ or more formally we let
$$\tag1 f(k,0)=0$$
$$\tag2 f(k,m+1)=\sqrt{k+(k+1)f(k+2,m)}$$
$$\tag3 F(k)=\lim_{m\to\infty}f(k,m)$$
and are interested in $F(1)$.
To show existence of  the limit, first note that 
$$f(k,m)\le f(k,m+1)< k+4,$$
where the first inequality should be clear (or follows readily by induction on $m$) and the second inequality follows easily by induction on $m$ with the crucial step being
$$ \begin{align}f(k,m+1)&=\sqrt{k+(k+1)f(k+2,m)}\\&<\sqrt{k+(k+1)(k+6)}\\&=\sqrt{(k+4)^2-10}.\end{align}$$
Therefore, in $(3)$ we take the limit of an increasing and bounded sequence. We conclude that the limit exists and $$F(k)\le k+4.$$ 
Knowing that the limit exists, we are now allowed to conclude
$$ F(k)=\sqrt{k+(k+1)F(k+2)}$$
or 
$$\tag4F(k)^2=k+(k+1)F(k+2).$$
Since (quite clearly) $F(k+2)> F(k)$, we see that $F(k)$ is larger than the positive root of $p(X)=X^2-(k+1)X-k$, in particular
$ F(k)>k+1$.

Letting 
$$\delta(k)=k+4-F(k)\in[0,3) $$
we obtain from $(4)$
$$\tag52(k+4)\delta(k)-\delta(k)^2=10+(k+1)\delta(k+2).$$
Using the bound $0\le \delta(k)<3$ this gives us
$$\tag6\delta(k)>\frac 5{k+4} $$
and
$$ (2k+5)\delta(k)<10+(k+1)\delta(k+2),$$
$$\tag7 2\delta(k)+\frac{3\delta(k)-10}{k+1}<\delta(k+2)$$
Assume that for some $k$ we have $\delta(k)> \frac{10}{k+4}$.
Then $\frac{3\delta(k)-10}{k+1}>-\delta(k)0$ so that $q:=\frac{\delta(k+2)}{\delta(k)}>1$. But then $\frac{3\delta(k+2)-10}{k+3}>\frac{3\delta(k)-10}{k+1}$ so that $\frac{\delta(k+4)}{\delta(k+2)}\ge q$. By induction, $\delta(k+2m)\ge q^m\delta(k)$, which is absurd. We conclude
$$ \delta(k)<\frac{10}{k+4}.$$
In other words,
$$F(k)=k+4+\frac{5+\delta_2(k)}{k+4} $$
with $0<\delta_2(k)<5$.

This allows us to compute $F(1)$  with acceptable precision from just a few iterations of $(4)$. Unfortunately,
the computed value
$$F(1)=3.598544540688569092598791775885364010757216864766804489021\ldots $$
is not recognized by Plouffe's converter.